# Why the haskell map does not work with (-1)?

Tags: haskell

What was wrong with the following code?

```
map (+1) [1, 2, 3 ] ==  map (\x -> x + 1) [1, 2, 3]
map (1+) [1, 2, 3] == map (\x -> 1 + x) [1, 2, 3]
map (-1) [1, 2, 3]  == map (\x -> x - 1) [1, 2, 3]
map (1-) [1, 2, 3] == map (\x -> 1 - x) [1, 2, 3]
```

Why the following does not work?

```
map (-1) [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: because `(-1)` is a strange edge case in Haskell. (One of very very very few!) It is constrained to mean the number "negative 1", not a section of the `-` operator. Use the `subtract` function instead if you need this.

Comment: The error message could probably be clearer, but it suggests that `(-1)` does not have the type `Num a => a -> a` that you might expect it to have.

Comment: Also see the [`LexicalNegation`](https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/exts/lexical_negation.html?highlight=lexicalnegation#extension-LexicalNegation) extension of GHC 9 which would allow the section `(- 1)`, with separating whitespace.

Answer (score 3):

`(-1)` is interpreted as a number: minus one. You can use [**`subtract :: Num a => a -> a -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:subtract) to subtract a value:

```
map (subtract 1) [1, 2, 3]  == map (\x -> x - 1) [1, 2, 3]
```